# React native splited APK files not installing

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I am new in react native. my react native APK file (both debug and release) working fine in emulator and device. But the apk file size is large. i read react docs  "Split APKs by ABI to reduce file size" and successfully generated 2 apk files ("armeabi-v7a", "x86") but when installing those apk in my device "armeabi-v7a" apk is installed but saying Unfortunately apps has stopped and "x86" is not installing.(Android version)

Is there any other way to install these type's of apk files. Or i am doing anything wrong?
i havn't uploaded it playstore yet.

Comment: Is anybody faced this types of problem?

Comment: what is the android logcat when you see Unfortunately apps has stopped